# Printing a character each second

Tags: python, string

I am fairly new in python and I would like to print a character each second. What I normally see in StackOverFlow are steps to print the characters inside a list per second. What I want to do is basically generate like "*" each second. Let me illustrate.

```
time = int(input("enter time:...") #user will input any integer as reference for the total time.
# * printed after 1 second
# * //another one printed after 2 seconds
# ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just update, I was able to find a code that does what I want:

seconds = int(input("enter time: "))
for i in range(seconds - 1):
   current_time = time.localtime()
   timestamp = time.strftime("%I:%m:%S", current_time)
   time.sleep(1)
   print('*')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I'm guessing you want to get a total time from the user and print a character with a time interval of 1 second that adds up to the total time?

if that's the case here's the code,

````
import time #this module helps us use the cpu's time in our python programe

time_limt = int(input("enter your total time: ")) #make sure you dont name this variable as time as it would mess up the refrences
char = str(input("enter the chracter you want to print: "))

for i in range(time_limit): #this is for printing up to the time limit
    time.sleep(1) #this stops the programe for 1 second
    print(char)```
````

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, I am not sure your question. I guess you want to ask how to print a charactor by limiting time, every other one second. For example:

```py
import time

print(*)
time.sleep(1)
```

if you have any question, please tell me, maybe I can help you. Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Thank you! First, it will ask the user a certain number which will be the total of number of seconds. So, for ex:

user_input = 10 //total number of seconds is 10

terminal will print

* will print after 1 second then
another * after 2 seconds then another * after 3 seconds.. until it reaches 10 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, this is the real code LOL:

seconds = int(input("enter time: "))
for i in range(seconds - 1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('*')

Answer (score -1):

```
def wait_k_seconds():
    import time
    k = int(input("enter time: "))
    for i in range(k-1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('*' * (i + 1), end = '\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('*' * k)
```